# Collections in Laravel. each function.

Tags: laravel, collections, each

I have tried to change the elements of a collection by each. Nothing is happening.

Minimum example:

```
$roles = $users->roles->each(function($role)
{
  $role->text = 'New text';
});
```

But is not working... the $roles collections is just the same as it was before the `.each` function. Any help?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Off the top of my head, it looks like the $roles collection is empty or you need to call `$role->save();` within the closure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` method instead of `each()`:

```
$users->roles->map(function($role)
{
    $role->text = 'New text';
});
```

Read the short docs about Collections: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/collections

Comment: E.g. 
    $roles = $user->roles->map(function($role)
    {
      $role->created_at = new \Datetime();
    });
    echo $roles->toJson();

I get [null]

Comment: @Kostas update you question with dump of Collection before `map()` and after (use `dd()`).

Comment: @Kostas show us the code you're actually rinning and collection before and after.

Comment: @Kostas the callback for map should return a value; otherwise, the result is an empty collection. Try this:
    $roles = $user->roles->map(function($role){$role->created_at = new \Datetime(); return $role; });
    echo $roles->toJson();

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a reference

```
$roles = $users->roles->each(function(&$role)
{
  $role->text = 'New text';
});
```

Or maybe this:

```
$roles = $users->roles;
$roles->each(function($role)
{
  $role->text = 'New text';
});
```

EDIT

Does a normal foreach work?

```
$roles = $users->roles;
foreach($roles as &$role){
  $role->text = 'New text';
});
```

Comment: I know it doesn't work!!! I'm struggling how to change an element from a collection but noone seems to provide a way!!!

Comment: No. Make answers, not questions :)

Comment: @limonte Sorry for trying to help. The normal foreach works for me. Im running 4.2. If that still doesnt work i suggest posting the whole controller or at least `dd($roles)` after the loop, the issue might be somewhere else.

Comment: This should work. Apparently he has other problem, maybe not getting the right collection, or reseting it on some point. Need to show his code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it was solved but I found the same in a query where I was doing a join.

It could be possible the problem is if you have a join inside the roles Relation.

I had, not working:

```
\BF\Models\RentalBike::active()
    ->has('sizes')
    ->whereHas('bike', function ($q) {
      $q->active();
    })
    ->whereHas('rental', function ($q) {
      $q->active();
    })
    ->with([
        'sizes' => function ($q) {
          $q->join('sizes', 'size_id', '=', 'sizes.id')
              ->orderBy('sizes.weight')
              ->get(['rental_bike_size.id',
                  'rental_bike_size.size_id',
                  'rental_bike_size.rental_bike_id',
                  'sizes.name',
                  'sizes.weight'
              ])->each(function($o) {                    
                $o->setAttribute('stock_available', 123);
              });
        },
        'bike' => function ($q) {
          $q->get(['id', 'model', 'brand_id']);
        },
        'bike.brand' => function ($q) {
          $q->get(['id', 'name']);
        }
    ])
    ->get(['id', 'id as rental_bike_id', 'bike_id', 'price_id']);
```

Solved with:

```
return \BF\Models\RentalBike::active()
    ->has('sizes')
    ->whereHas('bike', function ($q) {
      $q->active();
    })
    ->whereHas('rental', function ($q) {
      $q->active();
    })
    ->with([
        'sizes' => function ($q) {
          $q->join('sizes', 'size_id', '=', 'sizes.id')
              ->orderBy('sizes.weight')
              ->get(['rental_bike_size.id',
                  'rental_bike_size.size_id',
                  'rental_bike_size.rental_bike_id',
                  'sizes.name',
                  'sizes.weight'
              ]);
        },
        'bike' => function ($q) {
          $q->get(['id', 'model', 'brand_id']);
        },
        'bike.brand' => function ($q) {
          $q->get(['id', 'name']);
        }
    ])
    ->get(['id', 'id as rental_bike_id', 'bike_id', 'price_id'])
    ->each(function($o) {
      $o->sizes->each(function($o){
        $o->setAttribute('stock_available', 'bar');
      });          
    });
```

Note the .each() position.